# .NET BitmapSource is locking file

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this C# code to access an image file in order to read metadata from it.

```
BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(uri);
```

Unfortunately the image file specified by `uri` becomes locked until the program ends. How do I prevent the image from being locked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe [this could help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3cb97997-941f-42a8-a03b-f84b152c1139/) ?

***edit***

```
BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(uri,BitmapCreateOptions.None,BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

BitmapCreateOptions.None = default option

BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad = Caches the entire image into memory at load time. All requests for image data are filled from the memory store.

from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616004.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to delete/change the file immediately afterwards, read the whole file into memory, and then give it the `MemoryStream` instead. For example:

```
MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file));
BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use generic stream:

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
Bitmap template = new Bitmap(stream); // or (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromStream(stream)
stream.Close();
```

Comment: using (var stream = File.OpenRead()) is a better practice. Who knows, maybe new Bitmap() will throw an exception.